# PagerAdapter slow in first transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager along with a PagerAdapter, which downloads some images from a remote server (by their id) and shows them. It works almost perfectly, except for the fact that when swiping from the first to the second page, it is a bit slow (like 1 second), while all other transitions after that are normal. It is not a network issue because even if I wait a lot before swiping the issue remains.
Any ideas of why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

private SliderActivity activity;
private long[] imageIds;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

public SliderAdapter(Activity activity,
        long[] imageIds) {
    this.activity = (SliderActivity) activity;
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
    for (int i=0; i<imageIds.length; i++){
        new GetImageTask(imageIds[i]).execute();

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageIds.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

    if (images.size()-1 >= position && images.get(position) != null)
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));


    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);


    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

private class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = GetImageTask.class.getName();

    private Long id;

    public GetImageTask(Long id) {          
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Download image code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imgBmp) {
        if (imgBmp!=null) {

            images.add(imgBmp);
            activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: you mean it takes time to load just the 2nd page and the rest of the pages are loading okay?

Comment: yes. let's say there are 3 images. 1->2 is slow, then 2->3, 3->2, 2->1, 1->2 work perfectly.

Comment: it's like if the second page "wasn't ready" when I swipe to it. I also tried to switch to FragmentPagerAdapter and put pictures into different fragments, but the same exact issue remains.

Comment: i was reading about it last night and slept while doing so.. lol. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: The above link shows an animation that sould be similar to yours , there also its slow for the 2nd page and the rest transitions are fast and smmoth. its kind of strange.. i will get in touch if i find anything regrding the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was a question of excessive resolution of the images, which causes slowness while loading them. It is enough to add something like

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inDensity = 5;
options.inTargetDensity = 2;
Bitmap imgBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArray, 0,
                imgArray.length, options);
```

when decoding the image to reduce the resolution, and the viewpager suddently becomes smooth.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be due to images.. Read here for optimizing images 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

However if you still encounter issues read this also http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the picasso component to work with images. It'll help you because it can cache images.

You can find it here: http://square.github.io/picasso/